# Integration of a Gaussian function to count the number of particle under area

Tags: python, integration, gaussian

I need to count the number of particle under the fitted Gaussian curve. The area of the fitted curve can be found by integrating the function within the limit (mean-3*sigma) to  (mean+3*sigma). Would you please help me to solve this. Thanks for your kind consideration.

```
import pylab as py
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize
from scipy.stats import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

BackPFT='T067.csv'
df_180 = pd.read_csv(BackPFT, error_bad_lines=False, header=1)
x_180=df_180.iloc[:,3]
y_180=df_180.iloc[:,4]

#want  to plot the distribution of s calculated by the following equation 
s=np.sqrt((((16*x_180**2*38.22**2)/((4*38.22**2-y_180**2)**2))+1))-1
#Shape of this distribution is Gaussian 
#I need to fit this distribution by following parameter
mean=0.433
sigma=0.014
draw=s
#Definition of bin number
bi=np.linspace(0.01,8, 1000)
data = py.hist(draw.dropna(), bins = bi)
#Definition of Gaussian function 
def f(x, a, b, c):
    return (a * py.exp(-(x - mean)**2.0 / (2 *sigma**2)))
x = [0.5 * (data[1][i] + data[1][i+1]) for i in xrange(len(data[1])-1)]
y = data[0]
#Fitting the peak of the distribution
popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(f, x, y)
chi2, p = stats.chisquare(popt)
x_fit = py.linspace(x[0], x[-1], 80000)
y_fit = f(x_fit, *popt)
plot(x_fit, y_fit, lw=3, color="r",ls="--")
plt.xlim(0,2)
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=20)
plt.show()
```

The problem is how to integrate the defined function (f) and count the number under the area. Here I attach the file [T067.csv](https://ufile.io/jnuaa). Thanks in advance for your kind consideration.

Comment: There are a number of issues with this code. Please add comments in each important line so we can tell what is going on, or at least what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Gabriel Thanks for your kind concern. Here I edit as you want. If you need some more information please let me know.

Comment: You need to clean up your code removing as much as possible what is not essential. Also, describe the issue in detail.

Comment: @Gabriel Hope it is ok now. Thanks again for your kind response..

Comment: It is still not clear what you need. Please clean up your code, comment it thoroughly, and make sure it runs. Do you need to integrate a function? See here https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/integrate.html. To "count the number of particles under a function", have you tried simply subtracting the `y` coordinate of each particle from the `y` value evaluated in the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
BackPFT='T061.csv'

df_180 = pd.read_csv(BackPFT, skip_blank_lines=True ,skiprows=1,header=None,skipfooter=None,engine='python')

x_180=df_180.iloc[:,3]
y_180=df_180.iloc[:,4]

b=42.4
E=109.8
LET=24.19
REL=127.32

mean=0.339; m1=0.259
sigma=0.012; s1=0.015

s=np.sqrt((((16*x_180**2*b**2)/((4*b**2-y_180**2)**2))+1))-1
draw=s
bi=np.linspace(0,8, 2000)
binwidth=0.004
#I want to plot the dsitribution of s. This distribution has three gaussian peaks
data = py.hist(draw.dropna(), bins = bi,color='gray',)
#first Gaussian function for the first peak (peaks counted from the right)
def f(x, a, b, c):
    return (a * py.exp(-(x - mean)**2.0 / (2 *sigma**2)))
#  fitting the function (Gaussian)
x = [0.5 * (data[1][i] + data[1][i+1]) for i in xrange(len(data[1])-1)]
y = data[0]
popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(f, x, y)
chi, p = stats.chisquare(popt)
x_fit = py.linspace(x[0], x[-1], 80000)
y_fit = f(x_fit, *popt)
plot(x_fit, y_fit, lw=5, color="r",ls="--")

#integration of first function f
gaussF = lambda x, a: f(x, a, sigma, mean)
bins=((6*sigma)/(binwidth))
delta = ((mean+3*sigma) - (mean-3*sigma))/bins 
f1 = lambda x : f(x, popt[0], sigma, mean)
result = quad(f1,mean-3*sigma,mean+3*sigma)
area = result[0] # this give the area after integration of the gaussian
numPar = area / delta # this gives the number of particle under the integrated area
print"\n\tArea under curve = ", area, "\n\tNumber of particel= ", numPar
```

The file [T061.csv](https://ufile.io/9w1e9) here. Thanks Dr. I Putu Susila for his kind co-operation and interest.

Comment: @ Gabriel, Dear I was not able to make you clear my problem. But thanks for your kind concern and cooperation. I put my desire solution here. At last I found the solution. Thanks again for your kind help.